# Express throwing Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I don't really know why it's doing this, thanks for the help!

the intention is for it authenticate the cookie and redirect, but as of right now it authenticates just fine, but doesn't redirect.

```js
app.get('/admin-login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('admin-login', { title:'Admin login'});
    let key = req.cookies['loggedin']
    if (req.cookies['loggedin']) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM sync WHERE key = ?', [key], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
              return console.error(error.message);
            }
            if (results.length > 0) {
                res.redirect('/home');
            }
          });
    }
});
```

it's throwing this error though

```
/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:530:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:915:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:953:18)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodeprojects/website/app.js:46:16)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:149:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:133:8) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

Comment: You can't redirect if you're already rendered a response.